# Create select input with button in options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's possible to create a select input with a button or a link inside the options? I'd like to use it to list some values, and to have the option with a button to "Create Value" inside the options. I don't know if this is possible. I tried it with a href, but it treat it as text.

This would be the ideal scenario:

```
<select name="things">
    <option value="1">Thing One</option>
    <option value="2">Thing Two</option>
    <option value="3">Thing Three</option>
    <option value=""><button>New Thing</button></option>
</select>
```

I've search, but with no luck. Does somebody knows an jQuery plugin or something like might work?

Comment: No, you can't put any HTML inside of an `option` element, *just* text. You'll need to use either an list element to emulate a `select`, *or* use a change-handler on the `select` element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
$('select[name=things]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '')
    {
        var newThing = prompt('Enter a name for the new thing:');
        var newValue = $('option', this).length;
        $('<option>')
            .text(newThing)
            .attr('value', newValue)
            .insertBefore($('option[value=]', this));
        $(this).val(newValue);
    }
});
```

Of course, this could be done better, and more cleanly, but it's a start.

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/2v5gv/)

---

After reading your comments, it appears you simply want to redirect the user to another form when they select a given option. In that case, you can simply do this:

```
$('select[name=things]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '')
    {
        window.location.href = 'CreateThingForm'; // Replace with the actual URL
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do it this way, don't put button inside option.

alternatively you can :

```
<select name="things" onchange="checkAndAddOption(this)">
```

or

```
<select name="things" onclick="checkAndAddOption(this)">
.
.
.
</select>
<script>
function checkAndAddOption(selectElement) {
   if (selectElement.value === "") {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = 'newVal';
        opt.innerHTML = 'textToDisplay';
        selectElement.appendChild(opt);
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to do this, what I need is to redirect the user to the "Create Thing Form", when they click on the link or button inside the select.

Comment: Then, simply change the code to create option to location.href = 'url-of-form'